# Regex to strip \r and \n or \r\n

Tags: ruby, regex

I use the following regex to make newlines 
 tags:

```
str.gsub("\r\n", '<br>')
```

This works fine on a desktop. on an iphone text only has \n, it doesn't have the \r.

How can I make the regex support either? \r\n or just \n ?

Thanks

Comment: I do not know Ruby, but the standard thing is str.gsub("\r?\n", '<br>'). Try it.

Comment: Thanks, tried that but it didn't work. str = str.gsub("\r?\n", '<br>')   nothing had a br tag

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`\r\n|\r|\n`

That regular expression will also let you support Macs, which use `\r` alone as a line ending. Since regexes are greedy, they will match the `\r\n` as opposed to the individual ones if possible.

Comment: I got it to kinda work with.. but now it has 2 BRs.. I only want one? str = str.gsub(/\r\n|\r|\n/, '<br>')

Comment: Hmm, that's strange. Well, maybe it'll be more reliable if you first call replace with `\r\n`, then call it again with `\r|\n`, just to avoid regex` confusion.

Answer (score 12):

I think

```
str.gsub(/\r?\n/, '<br>')
```

should do the job

Comment: Thanks but that didn't work: str = str.gsub("/\r?\n/", '<br>')

Comment: @AnApprentice you wrote it with parentheses and regexp should be without them - I just checked the syntax of Ruby

Comment: Don't use double quote(") for the first parameter.

Comment: +1 this is the correct answer, but you need to use the `/` character round the pattern, instead of the `"` character.

Answer (score 1):

the `?` operator will accept 0 or one of the preceding element so `\r?\n` should accept `\r or \n or \r\n`

Comment: That didn't work. neither are matching now?       str = str.gsub("\r?\n", '<br>')

Comment: The ? needs to go after the \n.  In this case it should go after the term it is qualifying/limiting. As it is, it is qualifying the '\r'.  This works for me: `str = str.gsub(/\r(\n)?/,'<br>')`

Answer (score 1):

This is probably the easiest way :

```
str.gsub(/\R/, '<br>')
```

`/\R/` works for Mac/Linux/Windows and includes more exotic unicode newlines.

Comment: Nice thanks! Also easier to remember and more robust.

Answer (score 0):

`\r?\n|\r`

`\r?\n` will match  `\n` or `\r\n`.

`\r` will match just `\r`.

This should work for Windows\Mac\Linux EOLs.